# How to use Kendo upload for angular to upload to S3 with a progress indicator

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, file-upload, kendo-ui

I am unclear how the kendo upload communicates with the server to get the progress indicator.  In my application the progress indicator always goes from directly from 0% to complete regardless of file size.   I have the S3Helper on the server logging status but I don't know how to make that status known to the client.  How do I make the upload progress meter report status correctly.

Upload Service

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ARLNService.Helpers;
using ARLNService.Models;
using ARLNService.Services;
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.IO;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ARLNService.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
    [ApiController]
    [ApiVersionNeutral]
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class UploadFilesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly ARLNServiceContext _db;


        public UploadFilesController(
               IConfiguration configuration,
                    ARLNServiceContext db)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _db = db;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IList<IFormFile> files)
        {

            String bucket = _configuration["AWS:bucket"];
            String accessKey = _configuration["AWS:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"];

            System.DateTime thisDay = System.DateTime.Now;

            // I'm getting file inside Request object
            var file = this.Request.Form.Files[0];

            // create unique file name for prevent the mess
            var fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + file.FileName;

            string userName = this.Request.Form["userName"].ToString();

            Upload upload = new Upload();
            upload.fileName = fileName;
            upload.uploadDate = thisDay;
            upload.userName = userName;
            upload.originalFileName = file.FileName;
            _db.Set<Upload>().Add(upload);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            var fileResponse =  await S3Service.UploadObject(file, fileName, bucket, fileName, userName);

            Upload uploadUpdate = _db.Uploads.FirstOrDefault(c => c.fileName == fileName);


            if (fileResponse.success == true)
            {
                uploadUpdate.uploadStatus = "Uploaded";
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return Ok();
            }
            else
            {
                uploadUpdate.uploadStatus = "Upload Failed";
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return BadRequest("Failed to upload file");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Helper function for S3

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using ARLNService.Models;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Amazon.S3.Transfer;

namespace ARLNService.Helpers
{
    public class S3Service
    {


        public async static Task<UploadFile> UploadObject(IFormFile file, String fileName, String bucket,  String accessKey, String userName)
        {
            // connecting to the client
            var client = new AmazonS3Client();


            // get the file and convert it to the byte[]
            byte[] fileBytes = new Byte[file.Length];
            file.OpenReadStream().Read(fileBytes, 0, Int32.Parse(file.Length.ToString()));



            try
            {
                using (System.IO.MemoryStream filestream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(fileBytes))
                {

                    using (Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility tranUtility =
                      new Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility(client))
                    {

                        var request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
                        {
                            BucketName = bucket,
                            Key = accessKey,
                            InputStream = filestream
                        };

                        request.Metadata.Add("userName", userName);

                        request.UploadProgressEvent += new EventHandler<UploadProgressArgs> (uploadRequest_UploadPartProgressEvent);

                        await tranUtility.UploadAsync(request);

                     }
                }

                return new UploadFile
                {
                    success = true,
                    fileName = fileName
                };
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new UploadFile
                {
                    success = false,
                    fileName = fileName
                };
            }
        }

        static void uploadRequest_UploadPartProgressEvent(object sender, UploadProgressArgs e)
        {
            // Process event.
            Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}", e.TransferredBytes, e.TotalBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Angular Component

```
<div class="filters    " (click)="activate()">

  <div class="confirmMessage">
    <p>Choose select file to upload a .csv file.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdownSection">

    <kendo-upload #myUpload="kendoUpload" [saveUrl]="uploadSaveUrl"
                  (upload)="uploadEventHandler($event)"
                  (success)="loadItems($event)"
                  [removeUrl]="uploadRemoveUrl"
                  [restrictions]="myRestrictions"
                   [multiple]="false"
                  [accept]="acceptString">
      <kendo-upload-messages select="Select file...">
      </kendo-upload-messages>
    </kendo-upload>
    <br />

  </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Angular Code

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, ChangeDetectorRef, Injector, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { IPageInfo, IMetadata, IEntry, IRootObject } from '../../models/eipMessage';
import { DataService } from '../../shared/data.services';
import { UtilService } from '../../shared/util.service';
import { UtilityService } from '../../shared/utility.service';

import { ErrorMessageService } from '../../shared/error-message.service';
import { GlobalService } from '../../shared/global.service';
import { MatDatepicker, MatDatepickerInput, MatDatepickerToggle } from '@angular/material';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { FileRestrictions, UploadEvent, FileState } from '@progress/kendo-angular-upload';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { Observable, of, concat } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'uploads-file-select',
  templateUrl: 'uploads-file-select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['uploads-file-select.component.scss']
})
export class UploadsFileSelectComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  public acceptString = ".txt, .csv";
  public uploadSaveUrl = environment.serviceUrl + "api/UploadFiles/UploadFile"; // should represent an actual API endpoint
  myRestrictions: FileRestrictions = {
    allowedExtensions: ['.csv', '.txt']
  };

  @Output() fileUploaded = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private utilityService: UtilityService,  private dataService: DataService, private errMsgService: ErrorMessageService,
    private injector: Injector, private changeRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private utilService: UtilService, private globalService: GlobalService) {
  }


  uploadEventHandler(e: UploadEvent) {
    e.data = {
      userName: "tester@lab.com"
    };
  }

  public remove(upload, uid: string) {
    console.log("remove" + uid);
    upload.removeFilesByUid(uid);
  }

  public loadItems(event) {
    console.log("load itemas");
    this.fileUploaded.emit();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {

  }

  activate() {

  };

}
```

Comment: where is the code which actually makes the `post` request to server?

Comment: Ikendo abstracts that and autouplads based on the configuration in the html.   I don’t know what it’s doing under the covers